# Returning a result from join

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am struggling to return a value from join. I think the problem is in placing the "return" word, but i cant find any documentation on it.

I put some comments in code to explain my problem better.

```js
this.databaseService.getAlbumName(0).then(result =>{
    return result;
}).then(snap => {
    //snap return what I want so albumName.
    //Problem start when getPhotosFromAlbum(snap) kicks is.
    return this.databaseService.getPhotosFromAlbum(snap).then(photoResult => {
        //Am I returning value(array) from getPhotosFromAlbum(snap) in correct place?
        return photoResult;
    }).then(snapp => {
        //this part if just to display photoResult which is currently equal
        //to [Object object]
        console.log('array of photos: ' + snapp);
    })
```

And:

```js
    public getPhotosFromAlbum(albumName: string): any{
        //getting access to all Photos in album
        let photosInAlbum = firebase.database().ref('PhotosInAlbum' + '/' + albumName)
        return photosInAlbum.once('value', snap => {
            let photoRef = this.databaseRef.child('Photo');
            photoRef.once('value', photoSnap => {
                let photos = photoSnap.val();
                //creating an accessible array
                let keys = Object.keys(photos);
                var k = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
                    k.push(keys[i]);
                }
                console.log('From get Function: ' + k);
                return k;
            })    
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getPhotosFromAlbum` doesn't return a promise as far as I can see.

```
public getPhotosFromAlbum(albumName: string): any{
    let photosInAlbum = firebase.database().ref('PhotosInAlbum' + '/' + albumName)
    return photosInAlbum.once('value').then(snap => {
        let photoRef = this.databaseRef.child('Photo');
        return photoRef.once('value').then(photoSnap => {
            let photos = photoSnap.val();
            //creating an accessible array
            let keys = Object.keys(photos);
            var k = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
                k.push(keys[i]);
            }
            return k;
        })    
    })
}
```

That innermost listener seems to be a quite convoluted way to do:

```
        return photoRef.once('value').then(photoSnap => {
            return Object.keys(photoSnap.val());
        })
```

Comment: I tried put his line "return photosInAlbum.once('value').then and so one. I did this in  getAlbumName it work but in getAlbumName there is not join. geTPhotosFromAlbum contains a join, and i dont know where should i return "k".

Comment: I did as u told me to, unfortunatelly when i console.log(photosnap.val()) right before return it displays what i want. But when i want to access it outside of this promise chain it returns [Object object]